# Django clickjacking middleware and Firefox embedded PDFs

Tags: django, pdf, firefox, x-frame-options

I recently added clickjacking protection to a Django app with `django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware` but found that PDFs no longer load in Firefox.  While Chrome, Safari, and Edge embed the PDF as expected, Firefox throws the following console error:

`Load denied by X-Frame-Options: <site_base>/<file_path>.pdf does not permit framing.`

I found the `@xframe_options_exempt` decorator that I thought would help, but that just wraps a view whereas these are served directly through Apache.  The only fix I've found is to get the "Ignore X-Frame-Options Header" browser plugin which isn't really a customer friendly solution.

I've tried using `<embed>`, `<object>`, and `<iframe>` to embed the PDF and all cause the same browser console error, and if I remove the clickjacking middleware the PDFs load just fine again.

Anyone run into something like this before?  Relevant code:

```html
<select id="pdf_graph_selection" onchange="updatePDF()">
    {% for pdf_graph in pdf_graphs %}
        <option value="{{pdf_graph.url"}}>{{pdf_graph.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
<div id="pdf_container"></div>
```

```js
function updatePDF() {
    let new_source = $("#pdf_graph_selection").val();
    let new_graph = "'<embed src='" + new_source + "' width='70%' height='900px' class='pdf_embed'></embed>;
    $("#pdf_container").html(new_graph);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My coworker was able to help figure it out - We had a custom file response handler that must have been doing something Firefox didn't like.  By adding the `@xframe_options_sameorigin` decorator it is now working.